# error deploying to iOS from Flash Builder - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS

Tags: ios, eclipse, actionscript-3, macos, flash-builder

I have tried testing (both fast and standard) as well as full-blown deploying to an iPad via Flash Builder. In all cases I get:

> Error occurred while packaging the application:
>
> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
>   -Xmx1024m NotAfter: Sun Aug 21 22:15:11 IDT 2011

Any idea why and what the fix is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ios developer license is expired.

**"Sun Aug 21 22:15:11 IDT 2011"** is the **expired date.**
You need to re-create the Certificate and Provisioning file for your app.